# How to increase the Mysql Connection limit in etc/my.cnf

Tags: mysql, linux, centos6

I want to increase the max connection limit in mysql.

My current file **/etc/my.cnf** looks like this

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table=1
```

When I try to increase the connection limit by adding this variable then I cannot restart mysql service.

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table=1
set-variable=max_connections=10000
```

Comment: What about just

max_connections=10000, and by the way number is too high

Comment: @ZdenekMachek Thanks. It works now. I have set it to 2000 now instead of 10000

Answer (score 0):

You can change the limit from your mysql config file which is located in where you have installed the mysql server database, .ini file

search for the max_connection variable and change the value as per your request

and you have restart your server after changing